# Как настроить прием данных сервера в отладчике?

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

Во время отладки `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` равна `null` и вылетает предупреждение `PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "REQUEST_URI" in /var/www/haruproject.space/index.php on line 2`. Но когда я получаю ее значение через `var_dump($_SERVER)`, то я получаю `'REQUEST_URI' => string '/' (length=1)` - то есть все работает без проблем.

Вопрос - что нужно сделать чтобы получать значения переменной `$_SERVER` во время отладки?

Вот код:

```
<?php
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><?= var_dump($_SERVER) ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzx8Z.png)
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]
[image: 8]

Comment: Уже не первый вопрос об одном и том же..... и везде ни один раз уже вам сказали: REQUEST_URI  нет только если запускать код из консоли........ к отладке это не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я бы и рад не задавать их)) но что мне делать если код не работает, а чтобы найти ошибку нужен отладчик, который тоже не работает)) после прошлого вопроса и нескольких часов гуглежа я хотя бы нашел где смотреть эти переменные, может и после этого раза что-то новое смогу узнать. В доках по xdebug нашел это https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc --- но ни тебе гайда ни доков по тому как этим пользоваться, хотя судя по тому что написано в документации по xdebug - это вероятно могло бы помочь решить мою проблему

Comment: Какой код не работает? Если запустить php-код из вопроса в браузере (типа localhost/index.php) то все выведется, все будет видно.

Comment: @u_mulder Речь о коде из предыдущих недавних вопросов Алексей вкурсе)

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman я давал ссылку на то как настроить отладчик и настроить тот же phpstorm - там всё написано...... более того даже писал как происходить процесс запроса страницы из браузера на сервер и что никакие расширения не нужны........ 1) нужно настроить отладик на сервере - ссылку я давал. 2) нужно настроить отладку в IDE  - по ссылке как минимум есть Phpstorm. 3) ставим брейкпойнт, перезагружаем страницу в браузере и брейкпойнт подхватывается. всё ..................... теперь вопрос: зачем ты из консоли что-то запускаешь?

Comment: @u_mulder думаю лучше перефразировать свой вопрос) если Вас не затруднит - расскажите как Вы отлаживаете php код когда вам нужно знать во время отладки что находится в глобальных переменных, какими инструментами вы пользуетесь? через что вы вообще все это запускаете и т д

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman он, как и большинство наверняка использует xdebug  и какую-то IDE.  .... об этом всём написано тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482   ..... о чём я уже давал ссылку

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Проблема как раз таки в том что брейкпоинт не подхватывается, страница как загружалась до настройки отладчика без остановки так и после настройки также загружается от и до без остановки

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я уже не знаю что гуглить, все доки перевернул и примеры рабочих конфигураций гуглил - но их просто нет - что я должен прописать в настройках xdebuga чтобы он начал останавливать загрузку страницы на  брейкпоинте

Comment: Ты **всё сделал** что описано в инструкции? И убедился что phpinfo выводит информацию об xdebug?   ...........какую IDE используешь?

Comment: "Проблема как раз таки в том что брейкпоинт не подхватывается, страница как загружалась до настройки отладчика"  ---- тогда как понимать твои слова "Во время **отладки** $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] равна null" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский VSCode, все настройки из той ссылки что вы мне тогда прислали я прописал ( все фото прикрепил к вопросу) по поводу `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = NULL` фото там же

Comment: А что на счёт вопроса про "*Проблема как раз таки в том что брейкпоинт не подхватывается, страница как загружалась до настройки отладчика*" ---- тогда как понимать слова "*Во время **отладки** $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] равна null*" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский фото прикрепил, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=null` Но это как я понимаю значение по умолчанию когда `'PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "REQUEST_URI" '`

Comment: Никаких REQUEST_URI на фото нет........... Что ты в целом подразумеваешь под отладкой? ты пишешь *Во время отладки $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] равна null*. Что ты делаешь что ты считаешь отладкой?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский фото передобавил теперь должно отображаться. На данный момент доступный для меня способ отладки это в VSCode выставить брейкпоинты в местах где предположительно ошибка, здесь же перехожу на вкладку  `Run & Debug`, нажимаю на кнопку отладки - программа останавливается в нужном мне месте

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и соответственно проходя по коду где-то построчно где-то прыгая по брейкпоинтам смотрю что находится в этот момент в переменных пытаясь найти ошибку

Comment: И это и есть отладка, то есть всё же отладка работает))  Только скорее она на уровне отладки скрипта, а не приложения. А нужно наверное настроить так, чтобы отладить именно приложение (как это настроить в VS Code не смогу сказать )........... вообще в целом могу написать следующее: 1) версия дебага новая и она работает на порту 9003 - а не 9001 как старый. То есть в настройках скорее это нужно указать....2) попробуй пхпшторм))  3) https://habr.com/ru/post/310708/  настройка VS Code с отладкой... 4) самое главное - надо именно приложение отлаживать. при отладке скрипта есессно REQUEST_URI нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Очань вам благодарен))) напоследок - в чем разница для отладчика между скриптом и приложением? P.S. порт уже 9003 но это не помогает))

Comment: в локальности....... примерно как: поискать предмет исключительно на полке в шкафу и поискать предмет во всей квартире обыскав любые закоулки уголки шкафы полки балконы и пр......как-то так